# Recording from online stream and listening to it at the same time (ffmpeg / ffplay)

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, stream, mp3, rtp

Sometimes I like to record programmes from online radio channels, live or archived streams too. When there is no interesting actual programmes in the radios, I also would like listening to it at the same time while recording. I am using such command lines, which is called from Ruby script - to help parsing radios' timetables / programme pages and constructing the proper URLs of archived programmes which usually contains some timecode, such as 20160616_083000.mp3, etc.
So my command line to call from Ruby script looks like:

```
    programmes.each{|datepart,programme_length| 
      cmd=%Q{ffmpeg -y -i http://example.com/stream/#{datepart}.mp3 -t #{programme_length} -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 160k "#{fname}" -c copy -t #{programme_length} -f mp3 -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:8888}
      system cmd
}
```

It resides in a loop to record the previously parsed and selected programmes. Of cource the programmes are recorded properly and at the same time ffmpeg streams it as an mp3 rtp stream as well on localhost at the given port. In another terminal window I connect to the streamed data with one-liner as follows:

```
while true; do ffplay -i rtp://127.0.0.1:8888 -autoexit; done
```

I am using the -autoexit switch which should be stop playing the stream when it is ended and the "while" loop should be connect again to the new stream which is served by the programme recording "each" loop. Unfortunately it keeps playing after the end, and doesn't initiate a new connection to the newly started stream. How to use ffplay properly to stop playing after rtp stream is ended and let it connect again to the new stream?